# linux + sed - replace only the right most side char of string

Tags: linux, sed

I have linux machine red-hat 5.1

how to replace only the right single char (most side of string)

example from my sed syntax (not good because its replaced both "a" chars)
l

```
 echo machine1a | sed s'/a/b/g'

 mbchine1b
```

But the requested answer should be - **machine1b**
and not   mbchine1b

Comment: requested answer is the same as a task ?? if echo machine1a | sed s'/a/b/' SHOULD return the same string then I dont know why are you trying to sed it...just echo it. Unless you meant to say machine1b ?

Comment: see my update - you right I forget the "g" in the sed

Comment: are you trying to replace the last `a` with `b`? or are you trying to replace whatever the last character is?

Comment: why not use another tool than 'awk'. Here is the same functionality 'tcl: #!/usr/bin/tclsh

set nameA "MachineA";
set nameB "[string range $nameA 0 end-1]B";
puts "$nameA\t$nameB" '

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the end-of-pattern-space pattern. The pattern `$` matches the null string at the end of the pattern space. With this pattern you can avoid using `rev` as advised above.

```
  $ echo machine1a | sed 's/a$/b/'
  machine1b
```

Comment: This is what you should use. I don't think you need the '-e' though.

Comment: @opsguy Thank you. `-e` is not necessary unless several scripts are supplied on the command line. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
% echo machine1a | rev | sed s'/a/b/' | rev
machine1b
```

I can't find a way to do this with sed alone. There is a flag to the s operation specifies to only replace the Nth match, but counting from the end doesn't work.

```
% echo machine1a | sed s'/a/b/2'
machine1b
```

Comment: I dont have the rev command

Comment: awesome solution! :) @Eytan, read below my generic bash answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible using one simple sed expression. Instead do something like this ie. use bash's string manipulation capabilities:

```
var=machine1a; echo "${var%?}b"
```

But if you REALLY need sed then you can run the following command:

```
echo machine1a | sed s'/\(.*\)\(.\)$/\1b/g'
```

Sorry for confusion above by saying that it was not possible. I normally do this kind of stuff in bash using bash's string handling capabilities.

Comment: I do not think it is not possible. In sed you can use the `$` pattern that matches the end of the pattern space.

Comment: you are right...I dont know what was I thinking...probably because I normally do this kind of string operations using bash capabilities